# qmake - clean additional subdir

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

I have a Qt 4.8 project with subdir. I set my *.pro file to build a lib in this directory to use it with the core of my application. This works well.

The subdirectory uses a regular Makefile.

I'm now trying to add the possibility to clean this subdirectory by calling the clean command on the library's Makefile.

Here is what I got for now:

```
LIBS = bin/libfoo.a
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += somelib

# some lib
PRE_TARGETDEPS += somelib
somelib.commands = make -C lib/somelib LIB=../../bin/libfoo.a lib
somelib.clean_commands = make -C lib/somelib clean
```

I have no problem to compile my project with this lib.

But when I run 'make clean' on the qmake generated Makefile, 'make -C lib/somelib clean' is not called.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Can you post the output when you give make and make clean

Comment: Is this resolved now?

Comment: I couldn't find `myTarget.clean_commands` in the qmake docs, does it even exist?

Comment: The accepted answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29853832/198011) explains how to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding custom commands to existing targets in qmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853832/adding-custom-commands-to-existing-targets-in-qmake)