# Adding custom commands to existing targets in qmake

Tags: qt, makefile, target, qmake

Is there a way to specify, in a *.pro* file, extra commands to be added to  a standard target in the *Makefile* that `qmake` generates? For example, consider `distclean`, extra commands might be desired to:

- Remove **~* files.
- Clean out runtime-generated output files from the source tree.
- Etc.

I want to use the normal target and not a custom target because I want this to be completely transparent in my workflow. That is (again using `distclean` as an example), I don't want to...

- ... require knowledge in a multi-project setup that certain *Makefiles* use a custom rule instead of `distclean`.
- ... document custom rules, even for stand-alone projects, as `distclean` is already [well-known](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html) and intuitive<sup>†</sup>.

I found [How to add custom targets in a qmake generated Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776476), but this describes adding custom targets (which is [already documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html), even [back in 4.6](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qmake-environment-reference.html#customizing-makefile-output)) rather than adding rules to existing targets. While it does contain some hints, all of them require adding new custom targets, as specifying the same target more than once in a *Makefile* replaces (not adds) commands from the previous target.

The only thing I could really think of to try was to add `target.commands += new commands` to the *.pro* file as a wild guess (e.g `distclean.commands += rm \"*~\"`). This has no effect.

How can I transparently add custom commands to existing targets with `qmake`?

---

<sub><sup>†</sup> *For the `distclean` example: While `maintainer-clean` is also on that "standard target" list, in practice I have found it to be rarely used, and in any case `qmake` doesn't generate it by default; I consider it to be unsuitable.*</sub>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5948236

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two straightforward ways to accomplish this, depending on how self-contained / portable you want your solution to be and how lenient you want to be with the order of command execution.

---

## Option 1

The first option is to create a custom target in the *.pro* file for the new commands, then add that target as a prerequisite to the standard target that you are modifying. Going back to the `distclean` example, let's say you want to add a command to remove all **~* files:

1. Create a custom target in your *.pro* file. Note that you have to escape quotes and slashes in *.pro* files. For example, add:

   ```
   extraclean.commands = find . -name \"*~\" -exec rm -v {} \\;
   ```
2. Add this target as a dependency of the target you are modifying:

   ```
   distclean.depends = extraclean
   ```

   This won't actually modify the `distclean` rule just yet, as this method can't be used to modify existing rules. However...
3. Add both your new target and the target you are modifying as extra targets:

   ```
   QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += distclean extraclean
   ```

   This will add a second specification of `distclean` to the `Makefile`, but this works because [you can add dependencies to existing targets in `make` in separate rules, even though you can't add commands that way](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Rules.html#Multiple-Rules). If you were to also specify `distclean.commands` in your *.pro* file, you would break the existing `distclean` by replacing its default recipe.

So, putting that all together, in the *.pro* file:

```
extraclean.commands = find . -name \"*~\" -exec rm -v {} \\;
distclean.depends = extraclean
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += distclean extraclean
```

Where `extraclean` is some custom target with the commands you want to add, and `distclean` is the existing target that you wish to modify.

Pros:

- Completely self-contained in a *.pro* file.
- As portable as you can get, leaves the actual *Makefile* syntax and generation up to `qmake`.

Cons:

- Your new commands aren't *appended* to the existing recipe. Rather, they happen after all prerequisite targets are satisfied but *before* the existing recipe. In the `distclean` example, with the version of `qmake` that I'm using, this places the commands after the source tree clean but before *Makefile* itself is deleted (which is the only action the default recipe takes). This is not an issue for this example, but may be an issue for you.

---

## Option 2

The second option is to change the name of the *Makefile* that `qmake` generates, and create your own custom *Makefile* that *defers* to the generated one, rather than includes + overrides it. This is also a straightforward option; while not as self-contained as option 1, it gives you the ability to execute commands both before and after the default generated recipe.

You don't want to include + override the existing *Makefile*, because you don't want to replace the default recipes. If you do, you have to re-implement the default, but this can be an issue as that default may change (and you have to keep up with the changes). It's best to let `qmake` do as much work as possible, and not repeat its work.

To do this:

1. First, change the name of the file that `qmake` generates. This can be accomplished by adding a line such as this to the *.pro* file:

   ```
   MAKEFILE = RealMakefile
   ```

   That will cause `qmake` to output *RealMakefile* instead of *Makefile*.
2. The next step is to create your own `Makefile` with your custom commands. However, there are some caveats here. First, a full example, again using `distclean`. In a file named `Makefile`:

   ```
   .DEFAULT_GOAL := all

   %:
       @$(MAKE) -f RealMakefile $@

   distclean:
       @$(MAKE) -f RealMakefile $@ 
       @find . -name "*~" -exec rm -v {} \;
   ```

   Some notes about this:

   - We set `.DEFAULT_GOAL` because otherwise `distclean` would be the default. An alternative to this, if you're not comfortable with `.DEFAULT_GOAL`, is to specify an `all` rule using `@$(MAKE) -f RealMakefile $@` as the recipe.
   - The `%` target matches any target that isn't otherwise defined in this *Makefile*. It simply delegates processing to *RealMakefile*.
   - The `distclean` target is where we add our commands. We still need to delegate to *RealMakefile*, but additional commands can be added both before and after that happens.

Pros:

- More control over command order. Commands can be added both before and after the default recipe.

Cons:

- Not self-contained in a *.pro*.
- Not as portable: It doesn't leave all *Makefile* generation up to `qmake`, and also I'm not actually sure what parts are specific to GNU `make` here (comments welcome).

---

So, while this answer may be a little long, both of these methods are very straightforward. I would prefer option 1 unless the command execution order is an issue.

Comment: your solution is specific to the question and the "distclean" and "extraclean"... however I found it useful in a more generic way. FYI I used option-1. thanks! qmake is very very difficult to do this.

Comment: I replaced `distclean` here with plain old `clean` to get my custom clean commands to fire via the menu option in QtCreator.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add files you want to delete to the `QMAKE_CLEAN` and `QMAKE_DISTCLEAN` qmake variables.

```
build_tests {
    TINYORM_SQLITE_DATABASE = $$quote($$TINYORM_BUILD_TREE/tests/q_tinyorm_test_1.sqlite3)

    QMAKE_CLEAN = $$TINYORM_SQLITE_DATABASE
    QMAKE_DISTCLEAN = $$TINYORM_SQLITE_DATABASE
}
```

It is relevant only, when do you know files you want to delete, so in this case, you can not use `rm` command or some sort of globbing.